# android sending encoded image to webservice not working

Tags: android

I have created, following a tutorial (a lot of them) how to upload after choosing the gallery it proved to be not hard but after trying for a while to get it fixed the source of the problem proved to be when sending the encoded image to the web service. i have test the web service separately using online decoded image string and it works wonders but when i send the string from android it just casues an error and crashes the app. 
**android code**

```
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Base64;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.util.Pair;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;

ImageView uploadMe, downloadMe;
Button buttonUp, buttonDown;
EditText textUp, textDown;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    uploadMe = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageToUpload);
    downloadMe = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageToDownload);

    buttonUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUploadImage);
    buttonDown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDownloadImage);

    textUp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uploadName);
    textDown = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.downloadName);

    uploadMe.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUp.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonDown.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.imageToUpload:
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonUploadImage:
            Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) uploadMe.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

            String URL = "URL TO PHP FILE/upload_image.php?image=" + encodedImage + "&name=" + textUp.getText().toString(); //crashes when i send the string here
            new JSONTask().execute(URL);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonDownloadImage:

            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)
    {
        Uri selectedImg = data.getData();
        uploadMe.setImageURI(selectedImg);
    }
}

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    String error, content;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            content = buffer.toString();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            error = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            error = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
            try
            {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (error != null)
        {
            Log.d("JSON", error);
        }
        else
        {
            String output = "";

            JSONObject jsonResponse;

            try
            {
                jsonResponse = new JSONObject(content);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonResponse.getString("success"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}


}
```

I tried to fix it but it just messed everything up. is there a way to fix this without changing everything? maybe just the connection class
**Stacktrace**

```
01-27 21:21:47.232 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest D/dalvikvm: 

GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9429K, 31% free 17075K/24628K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
01-27 21:21:47.242 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2341K, 23% free 19115K/24628K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
01-27 21:21:47.342 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5395K, 17% free 18628K/22240K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
01-27 21:21:47.392 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2071K, 18% free 19436K/23696K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
01-27 21:21:47.482 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2707K, 18% free 21144K/25576K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
01-27 21:21:47.492 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3155K, 19% free 22399K/27456K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
01-27 21:21:47.512 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4382K, 24% free 22399K/29336K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
01-27 21:21:49.602 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err: java.io.EOFException
01-27 21:21:49.602 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.readAsciiLine(Util.java:318)
01-27 21:21:49.602 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:308)
01-27 21:21:49.602 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:135)
01-27 21:21:49.602 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:644)
01-27 21:21:49.602 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
01-27 21:21:49.602 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
01-27 21:21:49.602 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
01-27 21:21:49.602 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at com.blablabla.exportimagetest.MainActivity$JSONTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:116)
01-27 21:21:49.602 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at com.blablabla.exportimagetest.MainActivity$JSONTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:101)
01-27 21:21:49.602 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-27 21:21:49.602 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-27 21:21:49.602 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-27 21:21:49.602 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-27 21:21:49.602 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-27 21:21:49.602 4205-4221/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at com.blablabla.exportimagetest.MainActivity$JSONTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:172)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at com.blablabla.exportimagetest.MainActivity$JSONTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:101)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
01-27 21:21:49.612 4205-4205/com.blablabla.exportimagetest W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**edit**

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String urlParms = "image=" + encodedImage + "&name=" + nameValue;
        byte[] postData       = urlParms.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        int    postDataLength = postData.length;

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.2/web%20service%20owner_tenant/upload_image.php");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(postData);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            content = buffer.toString();
```

**PHP script**

```
<?php
//array for JSON response
$response = array();

require_once __DIR__ . '/connect.php';
$cnx = new DB_Connect();
$db = $cnx->connectMe();

if (!empty($_REQUEST['name']) && $_REQUEST['name'] != null
    && !empty($_REQUEST['image']) && $_REQUEST['image'] != null)
{   
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $image = $_REQUEST['image'];
    $response['error'] = "A | ";
    $decodedImage = base64_decode("$image");
    if (!$file = fopen("pictures/" . $name . ".PNG", 'wb')) {
        $response['error'] .= 'Failed to open | ';
    }
    if (fwrite($file, $decodedImage) === FALSE) {
        $response['error'] .= 'Failed to write';
    }
    fclose($file);

    //will be handled to correct response as later
    $response['success'] = '1';
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
    $response['success'] = '0';
    $response['message'] = 'Missing or Empty Parameter(s)';
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**update** 
I had, in my last run one final error in the web service i had to add this

```
    $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
```

Comment: What is the error? What line causes the error?

Comment: when i send the encdoedImage string to the web service it just wont work, the image is saved `.PNG` no name and content is corrupt or impossible to read. even thought i check the value of the encoded image & it's correct when i do it manually. at the `String URL = ...` as i have `encodedImage` sent there

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. Please edit your OP with the exact error message and stack trace and indicate which line causes the error.

Comment: i have added the stacktrace as requested and when i tracked this it was the `encodedImage` that caused that when send in the url

Comment: Print out your `content` string in the `postExecute` method of your JSONTask class.  It looks like `content` may not be a valid JSON string.

Comment: i have tested it and content is null when i send the string `encodedImage` in the url, when i don't it returns the correct json code

Comment: Where is `MainActivity.java:116`?

Comment: `jsonResponse = new JSONObject(content);` it's that when encodedImage is sent content doesn't take have a json result even thought it should

Comment: Well don't use `content` before you know it's valid json text. Is `content` initialised? Log it's content/value. Maybe it's a html error page instead of your exoected json text.

Comment: So you have a NullPointerException. Now tell what is null? Is it `content` ? You are sure it is not the Toast using jsonResponse.getString() ?

Comment: alright i fixed that part by initialsing content but i still have the issue where the image is not decoded as supposed. can the length of the string be cause to the problem or anything in it's content?

Comment: `had, in my last run one final error in the web service i had to add this

    $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);`. What error did you have? And what did it solve? The statement looks nonsense.

Comment: the image is saved correctly with a size but it still corrupt, after looking around i found someone replacing the space in the string with a +, so i tried it out. I thought the space doesn't cause an issue when decoding an image but apparently it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put an image in an url parameter for a GET request. That will not do as you can only send a small amount of bytes in an url. You should use the POST method.

Comment: can you please provide a working post method i tried a few but it didn't work, probably something i missed

Comment: You can find so many POST examples on this site. Nearly every day there is one. It's about the most common problem. So search or post the code you tried.

Comment: would any post type work? i thought there is a specific one for images

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by post type?

Comment: when sending images you add like an extra "thing" instead of the normal post , am i just wrong

Comment: Sorry but i have no idea where you are talking about. Please express your self better.

Comment: i have just used the POST method, but i have the issue. the image is saved in the location with the name but it's unreadable. that's why i am asking if images when using post should be treated differetnyl. i have edited the code so you can view the post use

Comment: Your php script is saving the image. You send a base64 encoded string. Is the php script saving the base64 string to file? If so you can open the file with a text editor and look at it contents.

Comment: I have made more tests today & i found out that the image sent is actually recieved in the web service with the exact ength of the encoded Image. when i checked that' how you decode an image in php, did i do something wrong??? maybe the extension is not correct?

Comment: You still have to comment on your code self first. What can you say for instance about `$decodedImage = base64_decode("$image");` ? Start with changing to $decodedImage = base64_decode($image); And did you open the file in a text editor? What did you see?

Comment: in php $foo is the same as "$foo", & i always open the files using a text editor

Comment: You are not serioisly and exactly answering on my questions.

Comment: i am trying to answer the question. you asked what is the error. there is no exact error as it writes & opens the file but it's just the encoded value that wasn't correctly "parsed". all i did after using post following your help and adjust the webservice so the encoded string doesn't contain an "unreadable" character